# use fixed-width font for tooltip

Tags: c, winapi, fonts, tooltip

I want to display some mouse event information in a tooltip. It looks like:

```
Win1 : x =  100; y =   99; dx =  655; dy = 1789;
Win2 : x = 2396; y =  133; dx =   78; dy =  111;
....
....
```

Even if I use `%4d` and other things to format the text, it doesn't give the perfect result as above.
Is there any way to display data in the format as above in tooltip? I can only imagine that one can use fixed-width font, but I don't have any idea how to change font in tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a handle to the [tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window.  Then you can send it a [WM_SETFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with the handle to a fixed-width font.